# Python/Boto - Writing to AWS CloudWatch Logs without sequence token

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to send logs to AWS CloudWatch Logs using Python and Boto framework. I am doing this:

```
res=logs.put_log_events("FOO", "BAR",
     [{'timestamp':int(round(time.time() * 1000)),
       'message':time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")+' Scheduled  monitoring check' }], 
     sequence_token=None)
```

I get an error each time I run:

```
boto.logs.exceptions.InvalidSequenceTokenException: InvalidSequenceTokenException: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The given sequenceToken is invalid. The next expected sequenceToken is: 49540113336360065754596906019042392283494234157161146226', u'expectedSequenceToken': u'49540113336360065754596906019042392283494234157161146226', u'__type': u'InvalidSequenceTokenException'}
```

It is somewhat impractical for me to store that token. It makes no sense, why can't I just append to the log stream ?

How can I get around this ?

Comment: I would take one from AWS' book and consider using a unique stream name per session.

eg. If you look at your lambda logs, each runtime writes to a unique stream (assuming each would manage their own token in-memory)

when looking at the logs, you can see them all aggregated anyway

Comment: @PeterMcIntyre This makes sense, but I wonder how you would do this in a lambda environment? You wouldn't be able to cache a token in memory across multiple invocations of a single lambda function, right?

Comment: with lambda you just print to stdout and Lambda takes care of the rest, the lambda analogy was just an example of how AWS themselves use Streams. If you really wanted to micro manage it, you could put the stream ID as a global variable which last as long as the function instance is "warm" (persists across non-concurrent invocations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get around it by first looking up the uploadSequenceToken via [describe_log_streams()](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_streams):

Essentially, the process is that you use the logStreamNamePrefix to specifically identify the logstream that you want to append to.  Then parse the uploadSequenceToken out of the response.

> *Response Syntax*
>
> ```
>  {
>      'logStreams': [
>          {
>              'logStreamName': 'string',
>              'creationTime': 123,
>              'firstEventTimestamp': 123,
>              'lastEventTimestamp': 123,
>              'lastIngestionTime': 123,
>              'uploadSequenceToken': 'string',
>              'arn': 'string',
>              'storedBytes': 123
>          },
>      ],
>      'nextToken': 'string'
>  }
> ```
>
> Returns all the log streams that are associated with the specified log group. The list returned in the response is ASCII-sorted by log stream name.
>
> By default, this operation returns up to 50 log streams. If there are more log streams to list, the response would contain a nextToken value in the response body. You can also limit the number of log streams returned in the response by specifying the limit parameter in the request. This operation has a limit of five transactions per second, after which transactions are throttled.
>
> *Request Syntax*
>
> ```
> response = client.describe_log_streams(
>     logGroupName='string',
>     logStreamNamePrefix='string',
>     orderBy='LogStreamName'|'LastEventTime',
>     descending=True|False,
>     nextToken='string',
>     limit=123
> )
> ```

Comment: Don't use DescribeLogStreams as it's got very low limits of 5 TPS per account per region and you'll very soon start getting throttled. Rather use PutLogEvents which has a much higher TPS of 5 TPS per log stream. Perform the 1st PutLogEvents without a sequence token in a try except block because, it'll return an error with the expected sequence token in the response error. Then simply use the returned "expected sequence token" when performing the PutLogEvents API call again in your except block. For example how to do this refer to https://gist.github.com/vatshat/63cad6f15082ec06851bb40eb0394931

Answer (score 22):

AWS Cloud Watch Putlogevent code

```
import boto3
import time


client = boto3.client('logs')

LOG_GROUP='cloudwatch_customlog'
LOG_STREAM='{}-{}'.format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),'logstream')

try:
   client.create_log_group(logGroupName=LOG_GROUP)
except client.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
   pass

try:
   client.create_log_stream(logGroupName=LOG_GROUP, logStreamName=LOG_STREAM)
except client.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
   pass

response = client.describe_log_streams(
   logGroupName=LOG_GROUP,
   logStreamNamePrefix=LOG_STREAM
)

event_log = {
   'logGroupName': LOG_GROUP,
   'logStreamName': LOG_STREAM,
   'logEvents': [
       {
           'timestamp': int(round(time.time() * 1000)),
           'message': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+'\t Your custom log messages'
       }
   ],
}

if 'uploadSequenceToken' in response['logStreams'][0]:
   event_log.update({'sequenceToken': response['logStreams'][0] ['uploadSequenceToken']})

response = client.put_log_events(**event_log)
print(response)
```

Comment: this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 6):

To answer the *why* part with an educated guess: It's the nature of a scalable asynchronous service.

If Amazon would *not* ask you to maintain a sequence number, then they could never scale out their CloudWatch service across many instances while still being able to guarantee that your logs appear in the **exact** same order as they happened (and imagine to how annoying out-of-order log entries would be when debugging a problem). Any tiny deviation in clocks, network latency, or other delay along the path to log acceptors would introduce ordering problems.

But since they *do* ask you for a sequence number, suddenly they can scale out their service easily and simply [merge-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) incoming log entries back while still retaining the correct log order, *your* log order.

Comment: Why isn't time stamp sufficient ?

Comment: Not sure. Could argue that even ms or µs resolution isn't accurate or deterministic enough. Or they encode some internals in the sequence number. Or they may simply want to force clients to use a single upload thread and think about client side batching.

Comment: Timestamp isn't sufficient because in AWS there is significant clock drift. (Although you should be using a system to sync clocks, that doesn't always happen.) Also, different logging frameworks and sources use different timestamp formats and timezones.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, that's how it works:

> Every PutLogEvents request must include the sequenceToken obtained from the response of the previous request. An upload in a newly created log stream does not require a sequenceToken.

([source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html))

Answer (score 4):

As it's mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html):

> You can also get the sequence token in the `expectedSequenceToken` field from `InvalidSequenceTokenException`.

However, the problem is that boto3 does not have the `expectedSequenceToken` field in the exception as it's discussed in [the issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1707):

> Boto3 doesn't support parsing additional parameters from exceptions, it only adds a Code and a Message. Labeling as a feature request, I think this is something we should add, but for now your best workaround would be to parse the error message.

Obviously, it's not ideal to parse the message to get the token because the format of the message may change. But it gives a simple working solution without calling `describe_log_streams`.

```
def append_log(group: str, stream: str, msg: str):
    logs = boto3.client('logs')

    def put(token=None, repeat: int = 0):
        events = [{
            'timestamp': int(round(time.time() * 1000)),
            'message': msg
        }]
        try:
            if token:
                logs.put_log_events(logGroupName=group, logStreamName=stream, logEvents=events, sequenceToken=token)
            else:
                logs.put_log_events(logGroupName=group, logStreamName=stream, logEvents=events)
        except (logs.exceptions.InvalidSequenceTokenException, logs.exceptions.DataAlreadyAcceptedException) as e:
            error_msg = e.response['Error']['Message']
            if repeat > 10:
                raise Exception("Too many repeats to write log")
            put(error_msg[error_msg.index(":") + 1:].strip(), repeat + 1)

    try:
        put()
    except logs.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
        try:
            logs.create_log_stream(logGroupName=group, logStreamName=stream)
        except logs.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
            logs.create_log_group(logGroupName=group)
            logs.create_log_stream(logGroupName=group, logStreamName=stream)
        put()
```

The function will create the group and the stream if it does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a logging class I created with help from the other answers here that doesn't require the logs:DescribeLogStreams IAM permission. This is meant to be a standalone module that can be imported (with the boto3 session passed in at class initialization).

```
import time

class CloudWatch:
    def __init__(self, boto3, log_group):
        self.client = boto3.client("logs")
        self.log_group = log_group
        self.sequence_token = None

    def log(self, message):
        
        print(message) # Delete this if you don't want stdout as well.

        log_stream = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        event_log = {
            'logGroupName': self.log_group,
            'logStreamName': log_stream,
            'logEvents': [
                {
                    'timestamp': int(round(time.time() * 1000)),
                    'message': message
                }
            ],
        }

        if self.sequence_token is not None:
            event_log.update({"sequenceToken" : self.sequence_token})

        for _ in range(3):
            try:
                response = self.client.put_log_events(**event_log)
                self.sequence_token = response["nextSequenceToken"]
                return
            except self.client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
                try:
                    self.client.create_log_group(logGroupName=self.log_group)
                except self.client.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
                    pass
                try:
                    self.client.create_log_stream(logGroupName=self.log_group, logStreamName=log_stream)
                except self.client.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
                    pass
            except self.client.exceptions.InvalidSequenceTokenException as e:
                event_log.update({"sequenceToken" : e.response["Error"]["Message"].split("is: ")[-1]})
                continue
            except self.client.exceptions.DataAlreadyAcceptedException:
                return
```

Answer (score 2):

Though most answers here work, BUT.. If you have multiple processes that write to the same stream really fast, they'll get the exception all the time, and if you put it in a loop, the same race condition applies. Everyone should be aware of that!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers on here are now outdated. As I look today, the docs for boto3 at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs/client/put_log_events.html say

> Warning The sequence token is now ignored in PutLogEvents actions

So these examples now contain unneeded complexity.

This might be useful as a simple cloudwatch logs client.

```
class CloudwatchLogs:
    def __init__(self, log_group):
        self.logs = boto3.client('logs')
        self.log_stream = f'{datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S")}-logstream'

        self.log_group = log_group
        self.created = False

    def _maybe_create(self):
        if not self.created:
            try:
                self.logs.create_log_stream(logGroupName=self.log_group, logStreamName=self.log_stream)
                self.created = True
            except self.logs.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
                pass

    def log(self, data: List[dict]):
        def as_cloudwatch(item) -> dict:
            return {'timestamp': int(time.time_ns() / 1_000_000), 'message': json.dumps(item)}

        self._maybe_create()

        self.logs.put_log_events(
            logGroupName=self.log_group,
            logStreamName=self.log_stream,
            logEvents=[as_cloudwatch(i) for i in data]
        )
```

Then you can say

```
logs = CloudwatchLogs(log_group="/log/group")
logs.log([ { "eventName": "NiceEvent", "text": "Something" } ] )
```